# Combine two data frames into one using values from each that are less than one, and apply to a list of data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I have lists of data frames that look like so:

```
0.015873016 0.016949153 0.018518519 0.025641026 0.022222222
0.05    0.156862745 0.018518519 0.026315789 0.071428571
0.015873016 0.016949153 0.018518519 0.025641026 0.022222222
0.015873016 0.016949153 0.018518519 0.025641026 0.022222222
0.032786885 0.017241379 0.08    0.114285714 0.022727273
0.015873016 0.016949153 0.018518519 0.025641026 0.022222222
0.015873016 0.016949153 0.018867925 0.025641026 0.022222222
63  59  54  39  45
0.015873016 0.016949153 0.018518519 0.025641026 0.022222222
0.015873016 0.016949153 0.018518519 0.025641026 0.022222222
0.06779661  0.072727273 0.058823529 0.083333333 0.097560976
0.032786885 0.035087719 0.038461538 0.026315789 0.046511628
0.016129032 0.035087719 0.038461538 0.083333333 0.071428571
0.016129032 0.017241379 0.018867925 0.054054054 0.022727273
0.015873016 0.016949153 0.018518519 0.025641026 0.022222222
```

But for each data frame in the list, I have a second list of data frames that correspond to the same data source, but were calculated differently, like so:

```
63.00   59.00   54.00   39.00   45.00
20.00   6.38    54.00   38.00   14.00
63.00   59.00   54.00   39.00   45.00
63.00   59.00   54.00   39.00   45.00
30.50   58.00   12.50   8.75    44.00
63.00   59.00   54.00   39.00   45.00
63.00   59.00   53.00   39.00   45.00
0.02    0.02    0.02    0.03    0.02
63.00   59.00   54.00   39.00   45.00
63.00   59.00   54.00   39.00   45.00
14.75   13.75   17.00   12.00   10.25
30.50   28.50   26.00   38.00   21.50
62.00   28.50   26.00   12.00   14.00
62.00   58.00   53.00   18.50   44.00
63.00   59.00   54.00   39.00   45.00
```

I want to combine the first data frame from the first list and the first data frame from the second list and so on, but using values from each data frame that are less than 1. So the output would look like this:

```
0.015873016 0.016949153 0.018518519 0.025641026 0.022222222
0.05    0.156862745 0.018518519 0.026315789 0.071428571
0.015873016 0.016949153 0.018518519 0.025641026 0.022222222
0.015873016 0.016949153 0.018518519 0.025641026 0.022222222
0.032786885 0.017241379 0.08    0.114285714 0.022727273
0.015873016 0.016949153 0.018518519 0.025641026 0.022222222
0.015873016 0.016949153 0.018867925 0.025641026 0.022222222
0.02    0.02    0.02    0.03    0.02
0.015873016 0.016949153 0.018518519 0.025641026 0.022222222
0.015873016 0.016949153 0.018518519 0.025641026 0.022222222
0.06779661  0.072727273 0.058823529 0.083333333 0.097560976
0.032786885 0.035087719 0.038461538 0.026315789 0.046511628
0.016129032 0.035087719 0.038461538 0.083333333 0.071428571
0.016129032 0.017241379 0.018867925 0.054054054 0.022727273
0.015873016 0.016949153 0.018518519 0.025641026 0.022222222
```

I have been trying to do this in R with no success. I am able to implement code in other programming languages, but the solution would need to include loading the lists of data frames. Thank you for any help!

Comment: What do you mean by `lists of data frames`? You showing just numbers, so it is hard to know what the structure of your data is. Can you be more explicit? How many dataframes in how many lists? How are they named? What columns do they have?

Comment: save the data.frames as numeric vectors `x1` and `x2` and define the new numeric vector `x` as `x = ifelse(x1  < 1, x1, x2)`. Finally, transform `x` into a data.frame

Comment: I mean I have many individual data frames, like you might for using lapply or sapply. I have one list of data frames containing 675 like the first example, and a second list of data frames containing 675 like the second example. This kind of code is used to read them into R files<-list.files(".", pattern=".txt")
new_list<-sapply(files, read.table, header=FALSE, check.names=FALSE)

Comment: As far as I know the output of sapply() is a vector or matrix—not a dataframe. And without understanding the structure of the data in each lost element I’m not certain how one would best help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pmin` to select the minimum value between the two dataframes. If your first list of dataframes is called `df1_list` and second one is called `df2_list` you can do :

```
result <- Map(pmin, df1_list, df2_list)
```